# How can I use an alias inside a sub-query?

Tags: sql, oracle

What I am trying to achieve is to get the rows having the maximum value from a table of the following form:

```
A | B | Ratio 
0 | 1 | 1.0
1 | 2 | 1.0
2 | 3 | 1.0
3 | 4 | 0.33
4 | 5 | 0.25
```

I am trying to display only rows containing the maximum value (in this case 1.0). May be I am not doing this right. I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT A,B,C 
FROM (---Long Sub Query--- Aliased as Full_Table)
WHERE RATIO=(SELECT MAX(RATIO) FROM Full_Table);
```

But Full_Table cannot be referenced from the second sub-query. There are some rows having the same maximum value which is the reason I was using this query. Is there a better construct to achieve this? In the worst case, I have to replace the second Full_Table by the entire long query but I'm hoping there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH Full_Table AS (---Long Sub Query---)
SELECT A,B,C 
FROM Full_Table
WHERE RATIO=(SELECT MAX(RATIO) FROM Full_Table);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT full_table.a,
       full_table.b,
       full_table.c
  FROM (SELECT ...,
               RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ratio DESC) AS rank
          FROM Sub Query---) full_table
 WHERE full_table.rank = 1
```

It's not clear if there can be more than one record returned, so I used `RANK()` rather than `ROW_NUMBER()` because `ROW_NUMBER` would only return one record.

You could incorporate that into a `WITH` clause, but it's still one pass over the derived table/inline view vs your two passes...

Oracle 9i+ supports the `WITH` syntax, calling it "Subquery Factoring".  Those coming from SQL Server 2005+ know the `WITH` syntax as a Common Table Expression (CTE).  Unlike SQL Server's implementation, the `WITH` syntax on Oracle 9i - 11g is *not* recursive - Oracle only added recursive WITH support (now that it's ANSI) in 11g R2, in part due to Oracle supporting recursive functionality with the `CONNECT BY` syntax (supported since Oracle v2). `WITH` syntax is syntactic sugar for derived tables/inline views - the query plan isn't reused for each instance.

```
WITH full_table AS (
  SELECT...)
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c
  FROM full_table x
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.ratio) AS max_ratio 
          FROM full_table t) y ON y.max_ratio = x.ratio
```

...is the identical to using:

```
SELECT x.a, x.b, x.c
  FROM (SELECT ...) x
  JOIN (SELECT MAX(t.ratio) AS max_ratio 
          FROM (SELECT ...) t) y ON y.max_ratio = x.ratio
```